# Comparing two spatial datasets statistically

Tags: coordinates

I'm new to this forum. I'm working on the following problem -

I have two datasets. Let's call it dataset A and B. Both of them will contain a set of points like

```
A1,LonA1,LatA1
A2,LonA2,LatA2
..
..
```

and

```
B1,LonB1,LatB1
B2,LonB2,LatB2
..
..
```

I also have link data for both A and B like A1->A2, A1->A3. So, I can essentially create a graph. I want to statistically compute how similar the two datasets (graphs) are. I want to say something dataset A is X% similar to dataset B.

I'm using coupled node edge scoring to compute similarity matrix and then use Hungarian algorithm to compute similarity between the graphs created. I was wondering if there is something simpler that I could do to do this. Thanks!

Comment: (1) What do your link data have to do with dataset B, since all links appear to be among records in A? Are you saying that both A and B are (directed) graphs or is there a typographical error and you mean that records in A are linked to records in B?  (2) What do you mean, exactly, by "similar"? Similar shapes? Having a tendency for paired points to be close? If you want any good answer you need to tell us; if you want a quantitative answer, you need to give us a quantitative definition.

Comment: @whuber: (1) Yes, both are graphs. Both A and B are something like this - http://semanticommunity.info/@api/deki/files/15822/Figure1.png?revision=1

Comment: 2) By similar I mean, how the datasets compare and contrast with each other. E.g., Say A has 3 nodes (A1,A2 and A3)) and 3 links (A1->A2,A2->A3,A1->A3). Similarly B has 4 nodes (B1,B2,B3,B4) and 3 links (B1->B2,B2->B3,B3->B4). It may be case that 2 nodes and 2 links from both A and B are same i.e., A1=B1, A2=B2, A1->A2 = B1->B2. And other nodes are different. In this 2 nodes from A is similar to 2 nodes in B i.e., 2/3 nodes (from A) and 2/4 nodes (from B) match.

Comment: So, nodes of A is approximately 78% similar to nodes of B. This is my method. I'm wondering if there is something else I could do in ArcGIS or any other tool to do this.